# I am unable to locate my saved text file in phone memory

Tags: android, file, memory, text

I am using this code to store a text file with the name of the time the 'Start' button in the app is pressed and further read it. I am trying to save the file in the memory where the app is installed by the user (i.e. SD Card or Phone Memory). The file I am storing is read and displayed in the logcat just fine but I can't find where is it saved in the memory (Phone or SD).

```
public void write_data(String s, Queue<SeismicDataPoint> t) throws IOException {

    String path = getBaseContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
    File dir = new File(path);
    if (!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdirs();
    FileOutputStream fOut = getBaseContext().openFileOutput(s + ".txt", MODE_APPEND);

    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
    SeismicDataPoint temp ;
    for(int i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++)

    {
        temp=t.poll();
        osw.append(temp.timestamp+" "+temp.x+" "+temp.y+" "+temp.z+"\n");

    }



    osw.flush();
    osw.close();


}
public void read_data(String s) throws IOException {



    BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(s+".txt"));
    while(true){
    String osw = b.readLine();

        if(osw==null)break;




}
```

Here is the manifest file too:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mycompany.falldetect" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getFilesDir point to internal storage directory. If you want something to store externally, then you should use path as

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
```

Read this too http://www.grokkingandroid.com/how-to-correctly-store-app-specific-files-in-android/

Update:Check this code

```
private void saveFile() {

    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/files");
    myDir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File (myDir, "sample.txt");
    if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(out);
        pw.println("my sample txt");
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I did as you suggested still I can't see the file stored

Comment: check the sample code, you can see a files folder in SDcard and inside that sample.txt

Comment: Which is your device? Post your latest code, let me test it on my side

Comment: I looked around the internet for a while and your code helped a lot. it works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Application private Data files are stored within `<internal_storage>/data/data/<package>`
If file is created as `MODE_PRIVATE` it is not possible to see/access that with apps such as a FileManager,etc.

Comment: is there any other method to store other than MODE_PRIVATE ?

Comment: MODE_WORLD_READABLE/MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE. . Also check other modes

Comment: but I am using MODE_APPEND

Comment: Here's another piece of code. I have tested it by creating an example on my side. Try this. The file is created successfully in the external directory. Let me know if you face issue with this code. -http://www.javatpoint.com/android-external-storage-example